# Using omp_get_num_threads() inside the parallel section

Tags: c, openmp

I would like to set the number of threads in OpenMP. When I use

```
omp_set_num_threads(2);
printf("nthread = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
#pragma omp parallel for
...
```

I see `nthreads=1`. Explained here, the number of reported threads belongs to serial section which is always 1. However, when I move it to the line after `#pragma`, I get compilation error that after `#pragma`, `for` is expected. So, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Well, yeah, `omp parallel for` expects a loop in the next line. You can call `omp_get_num_threads` inside that loop. Outside a parallel section, you can call `omp_get_max_threads` for the maximum number of threads to spawn. This is what you are looking for.

```
int max_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
#pragma omp parallel for
for(...) {
    int current_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    assert(current_threads == max_threads);
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
    int current_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
#   pragma omp for
    for(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That `omp_get_max_threads` returns the max value. As I set 2 in the original post, I expect to see 2, too.

Comment: OK. The two pragma blocks work for me. Problem is that when I printf after the `int current_threads` statement, I see 2 printfs (based on the number I set). The reason is that the printf is inside the parallel section. So the question is, how to print the number of threads once?

Comment: @ mahmood Use `#pragma omp single` or `#pragma omp master` (the first has an implicit barrier at the end, the latter does not have)